# Jquery dropdown list link

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

This is an example drop down list I have got in my program.
at the moment the link only works for this list, how do I make another drop down list work next to this one? how do I work around   `getElementById("list").value`?

Thanks for your help.

```
<select name="list" Id="list" accesskey="target">
    <option value='none' selected>Choose a Destination</option>
    <option value="europeresort.html">Europe</option>
    <option value="africaresort.html">Africa</option>
    <option value="northamericaresort.html">North America</option>
    <option value="southamericaresort.html">South America</option>
    <option value="thealpsresort.html">The Alps</option>
    <option value="carribeanresort.html">Carribean</option>
    <option value="indianoceanresort.html">Indian Ocean</option>
    <option value="asiaresort.html">Asia</option>
<select>
<input type=button value="Go" onclick="goToNewPage()" />
```

Comment: Not clear what you want to do.

Comment: I want to be able to use another drop down list next to this. But only the links on the first drop down list work. I want to add multiple lists with go buttons

Comment: What do mean by `next to this`? Next page or immediately after this dropdown. You should also  post your `html`.

Comment: immediately after this dropdown

Comment: // any other list immediately after don't work

    <select name="list" Id="list" accesskey="target">
    <option value='none' selected>Choose a Comfort Level</option>
    <option value="comfort3star.html">Comfort 3 star</option>
    <option value="comfort4star.html">Premium 4 star</option>
    <option value="comfort5star.html">Luxury 5 star</option>
<select>
<input type=button value="Go" onclick="goToNewPage()" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your two dropdown's `id`s are same. That why you always get the value of first dropdown. Following code snippet may help you.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="list" id="list" accesskey="target">
    <option value='none' selected>Choose a Destination</option>
    <option value="europeresort.html">Europe</option>
    <option value="africaresort.html">Africa</option>
    <option value="northamericaresort.html">North America</option>
    <option value="southamericaresort.html">South America</option>
    <option value="thealpsresort.html">The Alps</option>
    <option value="carribeanresort.html">Carribean</option>
    <option value="indianoceanresort.html">Indian Ocean</option>
    <option value="asiaresort.html">Asia</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Go"/>

<select name="list" id="list" accesskey="target">
    <option value='none' selected>Choose a Comfort Level</option>
    <option value="comfort3star.html">Comfort 3 star</option>
    <option value="theme2.html">Premium 4 star</option>
    <option value="theme3.html">Luxury 5 star</option>
</select>
 <input type="button" value="Go"/>

<script>
    $('input').click(function() {
        var url = $(this).prev('select').val();
        if (url != 'none')
            window.location = url;
    });
</script>
```